# ggplot2: how to reduce space between narrow width bars, after coord_flip, and panel border

Tags: r, ggplot2, width

When you have flipped coordinates, how do you reduce the space between bars that are narrow and the panel border?  Using the data frame df and the `ggplot` commands, there is much white space between the bottom bar and the tick marks (and similarly a wide space above the "vendor" bar).

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("firm", "vendor"), y = c(50, 20))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.4) + 
  theme_tufte() +  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = "", y = "")
```

[image]

I tried `scale_x_discrete` with both `limits` and `expand` arguments to no avail as well as `position = position dodge`, likewise with no effect.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859874/r-ggplot2-reducing-bar-width-and-spacing-between-bars) offers `coord_equal` to change the aspect ratio, and thereby reduce or eliminate the extra space, but notes that the solution *does not work with `coord_flip`*.

Comment: As far as I know `ggplot2` just scales the plot to the size of the window. Supposing you want to use the plot somewhere else, I suggest to plot with the `width` and `height` parameters in the png / jpg device when you save the plot. Another option is to click on the export button in RStudio, you get a pop-up where you can play with the setting. Mostly I'm using one of those two options.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the formating of my code, BTW.  I thought the RStudio export only adjusts the total plot size, not anything internal to the plot itself, such as space between bars.  Same for width/height parameters when choosing a device.  I am using this in a .Rnw file with Latex.

Comment: When adjusting the height of the total plot, also the internal spaces are altered. Unfortunately I cann't help with the integration in `.Rnw` files (no experience).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think I have found a solution. You can remove `width` from `geom_bar` and introduce `theme(aspect.ratio = .2)`, then you can play with the ratio to find the desired width. And unlike `coord_equal` or `coord_fixed` is compatible with `coord_flip`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  theme_tufte() + theme(aspect.ratio = .2) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = "", y = "")
```

[image]

Comment: Finally found the answer to this issue!