# R Adjusting space between bars after coord_flip() in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a chart with `ggplot`.

I have set the width of each bar, but I also want to set the spacing between the bars to a certain value (I want to reduce the spacing marked in red to 0.1, for example)? I know there are options like position_dodge, but that does not seem to work in combination with coord_flip().

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905926/ggplot2-how-to-reduce-space-between-narrow-width-bars-after-coord-flip-and-pa) related post it was suggested to use theme(aspect.ratio = .2), but this does not allow to additionally set the specific width of the bars.

Are there any suggestions to achieve this?

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(0)
numbers <- runif(5, 0, 10)
names <- LETTERS[seq(1, 5)]
df <- cbind.data.frame(names, numbers)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = names, y = numbers)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "blue", width = 0.30) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution is in the combination of

- the `width` argument of `geom_bar()` (which fills the space reserved for a bar)
- and the `aspect ratio` argument of `theme()`, which squeezes the plot vertically, leading to 'small' bars.

With the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
    ## your data
    set.seed(0)
    numbers <- runif(5, 0, 10)
    names <- LETTERS[seq(1, 5)]
    df <- cbind.data.frame(names, numbers)       ## corrected args
    
    ggplot(data = df, aes(x = names, y = numbers)) + 
      geom_bar(stat="identity", 
               fill = "blue", 
               width=0.9) +            ### increased
      theme(aspect.ratio = .2) +       ### aspect ratio added
      coord_flip()
```

you get the following graph:

[image]

Comment: From my point of view, theme(aspect.ratio) scales the entire chart. So it seems to work in this particular chart to get a reasonable fit by also adjusting the width of the bars. But if one has many charts, it would be great if the width can be set to a certain value and at the same time the distance between the bars can be set to a certain value, without using the scale factor.

Comment: One the one hand, I think I understand what you are saying. On the other hand, I don't think geom_bar was set up to work that way. The documentation of `width` in   `geom_bar`, indicates that these 'things' have been set up in a "relative" way: *Bar width. By default, set to 90% of the resolution of the data.*. If things are defined in a relative way, how could you then force them in an absolute format? I don't want to be right, I just think this is the only way in `ggplot2`. And of course, I might be wrong :-)

Comment: OP, when you have "many charts", are you referring to using facets or just... making many charts?  In your example, you only show the one plot, and this solution seems to fix that problem.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer to use the `ggstance` package to avoid messing around with `coord_flip`. you need to switch your x and y

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstance)

ggplot(df, aes(x = numbers, y = names)) +
  geom_colh(fill = "blue", width = 0.9)
```

[image]